# Equivalent definitions of homogeneous ideal

Tags: proof-verification, ideals, graded-rings

I need to show that an ideal $I$ of a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring R is homogeneous iff for every element $f \in I$, all homogeneous components of $f$ are in $I$.

$\Leftarrow$ implication is obviously.
$\Rightarrow$ implication is also obvious because if $I=(\{g_i\}) \ni f = \sum m_ig_i \space(g_i \in R_j$ for some $j$) and homogeneous components of $f$ are also combination of $g_i$.

But looking at the other proofs(such [this](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/an-ideal-of-rx-is-homogeneous-if-and-only-if-it-has-a-generating-set-consisting-only-of-homogeneous-polynomials/)) i realized i made a mistake, but i do not know where.

P.S.
$m_i^{(j)}$ is the homogeneous component of $m_{i}$ with $\deg m_i^{(j)} = j$.
Similarly for $f_i$.
$f_i = \sum\limits_{j:j + \deg(g_j) = i,r:any}m_{r}^{j}g_j \implies f_i \in I$

Comment: homogeneous ideal is an ideal generated by homogeneous elements.

Comment: You argument is not exactly wrong.  It is unclear.  As one example of what to clarify, notice the curly brackets around the first $g_i$ do not belong there.  Try to complete the clause following the "(."  Correct the ungrammatical part, and write it out a bit more fully.